# Android, Giant lag during doInBackground of Async Task (ACTUALLY: While inflating Views)

Tags: android, asynchronous

So basically i am just quickly going to tell you the app-flow,

one async task (a) fetches a source code from an url and passes it on to another async task (b) where there are several array copies and splits that need to be done, overall around 500 lines of code, yet as i said, a lot of if/for/split/arraycopy methods.. After that it reinitalizes the viewpager and the data is refreshed..

so while the data is being fetched and sorted the UI is supposed to show some sort of loading hint, what it does, but after about a second it completely lags out and the entire UI thread is blocked although all the work is done in the doInBackground methods.. i thought the doInBackground methods are supposed to handle the "heavy duty"..

Is there a certain limit or am I missing something out..

I will just post the rough async task i am using..

```
public class ProcessingService extends Service {

Method1();
Method2();
Method3();
//etc.. about 10 methods with ~500 lines of code.. 

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent iservice1, int flags, int startId) {
    processingit();
    return Service.START_NOT_STICKY;
}

public void processingit() {
    new ProcessingOutsourced().execute();
}

public class ProcessingOutsourced extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
    public void onPreExecute() {

    }

    public Void doInBackground(String... urls) {
        Method1();
        Method2();
        Method3();
        //Etc..
        return null;
    }

    public void onPostExecute(Void unused) { 
        Context b = getBaseContext();
        processing goon2 = new processing(b); //Passed onto another class to finish in entirely.. 
        goon2.finishLoading();
        stopSelf();
    }
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    //for communication return IBinder implementation
    return null;
}
}
```

So basically.. i believe that i am doing something wrong in the doInBackground part.. or am i not allowed to pass it onto another class? I would have liked to do everything in the async, yet i am not able to use "viewpager.notifydatasetchanged" in it.. thats why i need to pass it on.

ANY kind of hints are appreciated..!

EDIT:

So basically i am a really lazy person and used the viewpager fragment that uses the placeholder fragments and i used several if methods to find out which page is exactly being displayed and thus inflate a new view everytime a condition changes..

```
if (getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER) == 0) {
        if (ClassC.rdy == 0 && ClassC.PullFailedAndRefresh == 0) {
            View rootView11 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mat_while_loading_in_main, container, false);
            TextView textAbove = (TextView)rootView11.findViewById(R.id.whileloadingAbove);
            textAbove.setText("Vertretung Heute wird geladen...");
            return rootView11;
        }else if (ClassC.rdy == 0 && ClassC.PullFailedAndRefresh == 1) {
            View rootView1111 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mat_loading_aborted_refresh, container, false);
            return rootView1111;
        } else if (ClassC.rdy == 1 && ClassC.abwh.equalsIgnoreCase("Abw") && ClassC.datumh.equalsIgnoreCase("Vertretung Datum eintragen")) {
            View rootView11111 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mat_keine_vertretung_eingerichtet, container, false);
            return rootView11111;
        }  else if (ClassC.rdy == 1 && !ClassC.frageTimeout) {
            View rootView111 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mat_loading_aborted, container, false);
            return rootView111;
        } else if (ClassC.rdy == 1 && ClassC.pullWorked == 1) {
            View rootView2 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mat_vertretungsplan, container, false);
            TextView textView1 = (TextView) rootView2.findViewById(R.id.section_label);
            TextView textView121 = (TextView) rootView2.findViewById(R.id.spalte_1);    //SPALTE1
            TextView textView221 = (TextView) rootView2.findViewById(R.id.spalte_2);    //SPALTE2
            TextView textView321 = (TextView) rootView2.findViewById(R.id.spalte_3);    //SPALTE3
            TextView textView421 = (TextView) rootView2.findViewById(R.id.spalte_4);    //SPALTE4
            TextView textView521 = (TextView) rootView2.findViewById(R.id.spalte_5);    //SPALTE5
            TextView textView621 = (TextView) rootView2.findViewById(R.id.spalte_6);    //SPALTE6
            TextView textView721 = (TextView) rootView2.findViewById(R.id.spalte_7);    //SPALTE7
            TextView wat1 = (TextView) rootView2.findViewById(R.id.BonusHinweise);
            TextView textView31 = (TextView) rootView2.findViewById(R.id.Abwesendenliste);
            TextView textView41 = (TextView) rootView2.findViewById(R.id.GeneralHinweis);

            textView1.setTextSize(dgrose);
            textView1.setText(ClassC.datumh);     //DATUM-H
            textView121.setTextSize(vpgrose);
            textView121.setText(Html.fromHtml(ClassC.dieausgabeh1));    //SPALTE1_H
            textView221.setTextSize(vpgrose);
            textView221.setText(Html.fromHtml(ClassC.dieausgabeh2));    //SPALTE2_H
            textView321.setTextSize(vpgrose);
            textView321.setText(Html.fromHtml(ClassC.dieausgabeh3));    //SPALTE3_H
            textView421.setTextSize(vpgrose);
            textView421.setText(Html.fromHtml(ClassC.dieausgabeh4));    //SPALTE4_H
            textView521.setTextSize(vpgrose);
            textView521.setText(Html.fromHtml(ClassC.dieausgabeh5));    //SPALTE5_H
            textView621.setTextSize(vpgrose);
            textView621.setText(Html.fromHtml(ClassC.dieausgabeh6));    //SPALTE6_H
            textView721.setTextSize(vpgrose);
            textView721.setText(Html.fromHtml(ClassC.dieausgabeh7));    //SPALTE7_H
            textView31.setTextSize(agrose);
            textView31.setText(/*"\n" + */ClassC.abwh);      
            textView41.setTextSize(hgrose);
            textView41.setText(R.string.atung);       

            if (ClassC.watchh != 0) {
                wat1.setTextSize(hgrose);
                wat1.setText("");
            } else if (ClassC.abwfuckedup != 0) {
                wat1.setTextSize(hgrose);
                wat1.setText("");
            } else if (ClassC.watchh != 0 && ClassC.abwfuckedup != 0) {
                wat1.setTextSize(hgrose);
                wat1.setText("");
            } else {
                wat1.setTextSize(hgrose);
                wat1.setText("Kein Hinweis");
            }
            return rootView2;

        }
```

This is just one of the pages with 4 different states and seems like this is way too much. Should i create an individual class for each page? What could help apart from reading the android documentation.. :l?

Comment: im sure the lag is not happening inside doInBackground and its whatever you are doing in onPostExecute. did you try setting breakpoints and see where the lag starts to happen?

Comment: 1) Don't use `getBaseContext()`, use `this`.
2) What is class `processing`?

Comment: The idea with the breaking points made me find out that the lag was caused by inflating several views (4) what seems to be too much.. i will edit the main post when i return home

Answer (score 2):

```
public void onPostExecute(Void unused) { 
    Context b = getBaseContext();
    processing goon2 = new processing(b); //Passed onto another class to finish in entirely.. 
    goon2.finishLoading();
    stopSelf();
}
```

This code is running on the UI thread - *only doInBackground()* runs on a separate thread, onPostExecute() does not as it's expected that you'll use it to update your interface with the new data your task has fetched/produced.

As a result, any lengthy operations you run here will block the UI thread, which would cause the effect you're seeing.